# My C# code in HTML page is not showing indented comments

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, doxygen

I am using doxygen to build my API documentation website. When I build locally my code looks perfectly fine in my HTML page (See Pic. 1) But when I upload my files into my server, the C# code comment indents disappear (See Pic. 2). When I inspect both pages the CSS is the same. Why is this happening?

Picture 1 - Local Build
[image: Picture 1 - Local Build]

Picture 2 - Uploaded Online - https://roboticsys.com/RapidCode/absolute-motion-cs.html
[image: Picture 2 - Uploaded to the Server]

Comment: We can't debug screenshots; please check out [mcve]

Comment: There is no code to debug. If anything, you could click on the link provided and inspect the page.

Comment: Screenshots are based on doxygen and thus on code. Specify your doxygen version, changes of doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) compared to default file. Further provide the information as requested by TylerH

Comment: You can inspect the page with your browser and look at the code. The problem is not the code. The problem is the html format. I was able to fix it by unchecking the HTML minify option in cloudfare.